# Postgres improve large update performance?

Tags: postgresql, database-optimization

I'm migrating my Postgres database and am attempting to update a string value to a numeric value, like this:

```
UPDATE table SET column = 1 WHERE LENGTH(column) = 1;
```

This table contains around 20 million rows, and the update has been taking forever to run. I have an index on `LENGTH(column)` as well as 4 other indexes on different columns, one of which is a `UNIQUE` index on 2 columns. There's also a foreign key constraint on this table.

What could I do to speed this query up? If more information is needed, I'd be happy to provide it.

Comment: Depending on the expected percentage of rows updated and the current statistics it may be beneficial even drop the index on the target column (i.e, drop the index on `length(column)`). However, this could only be determined with EXPLAIN ANALYZE. But this would seem to make it a moot point as it runs the query. Since this is a migration it should be a 1 time event anyway (at least in user acceptance testing and production environments).

Answer (score 2):

Dropping constraints that affect the column and indexes (except the one that supports the `WHERE` condition) will speed up such an `UPDATE`.

You can also get a small performance gain from increasing `max_wal_size`.

Other than that, you just have to wait it out.